# Google indexing issues cause by redirect on a single page site

Tags: firebase, google-search-console, namecheap

I have deployed a single page website to Firebase and configured hosting with a custom domain from Namecheap.
On Firebase Hosting Console I've set the www to redirect to the apex as per the documentation, on Namecheap I have pointed the A records to the Firebase project IP and also added the TXT record, plus also added sitemap.xml and robots.txt to the project.
Everything seems to be working fine, but the site is not being properly indexed by google even after I have submitted it to be indexed - most of the times it doesn’t appear on search results and when it does it ranks really low even though it should be the main result.
When I visit Google Search Console, I can see that it shows two issues/reasons that are causing the page to not be indexed (marked as grey):

1. Redirect error - for the [www.miles2one.com](http://www.miles2one.com)
2. Page redirect - for http://miles2one.com (not sure why it shows http here since when I visit the site it shows https)
   It also shows that one is properly indexed (marked as green), and it is the apex one with https (https://miles2one.com).

I have tried to follow the steps listed on the documentation to fix these issues, but they are not helping: 
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203#multiple_redirects
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203#page_with_redirect

I’m not sure if this is relevant, but I have noticed that on the sitemaps page of the Google Search Console, there are two sitemaps marked as successful “https://miles2one.com/sitemap.xml” and “https://www.miles2one.com/sitemap.xml”, the latter having been submitted 1 week prior than the other.

What can I do to fix these issues and so that the page so that it is properly indexed and ideally the first result when I search for “Miles to one” or “Miles 2 one” on google?